Deploying Django Rest Framework Based Microservices That Communicate with Token Authentication
I am developing a docker based application. The application has two components.
A core component (CORE) and an interface component (INTERFACE).
The world communicates with the INTERFACE component.
The INTERFACE component CRUD the database in the CORE component.
The ultimate aim of this setup is that I might have different interface components. Also, it applies separation of concerns.
When deploying the app. Using docker compose I will establish the communication between the two applications. However, the INTERFACE should communicate with the CORE using Token Based Authentication.
My question is how to generate a Token for the INTERFACE inside the CORE during launch.
I tried developing a script that generates the token.
But it turns out the script requires some Environmental variables that Django Shell sets.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
